# Return monthly records from table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a log table with `[TimeStamp]` and `[Action]` columns:

| TimeStamp | Action |
| --- | --- |
| 2022-10-13 16:24:42.803 | ... |
| 2022-10-12 16:24:42.703 | ... |
| 2022-10-12 10:23:42.809 | ... |
| 2022-10-11 16:21:42.903 | ... |
| 2022-10-10 10:24:42.803 | ... |

I need to write a stored procedure that return records count for each month for the last 6 months

| Month | records |
| --- | --- |
| 2022-10 | 366 |
| 2022-09 | 193 |
| 2022-08 | 276 |
| 2022-07 | 233 |
| 2022-06 | 215 |
| 2022-05 | 117 |

I started with:

```
DECLARE @monthly_records TABLE (Month varchar(50), Records int) 
DECLARE @cnt INT = 0;

WHILE @cnt < 6
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO @monthly_records (Month, Records) 
    VALUES (? , ?)

    SET @cnt = @cnt + 1;
END

SELECT * 
FROM @monthly_records
```

Comment: Is the column TimeStamp of type `varchar(50)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming column `TimeStamp` is of type `DATETIME` you should be able to select it like that:

```
DECLARE @table TABLE ([TimeStamp] DATETIME) 

DECLARE @firstOfCurrentMonth AS DATETIME = DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(GETDATE()), MONTH(GETDATE()), 1)
DECLARE @dateOfInterest AS DATETIME = DATEADD(MONTH, -6, @firstOfCurrentMonth)

SELECT
    CAST(YEAR([TimeStamp]) AS VARCHAR(4)) + '-' + RIGHT('00' + CAST(MONTH([TimeStamp]) AS VARCHAR(2)), 2) AS [Month],
    COUNT(*) AS Records
FROM @table
WHERE [TimeStamp] > @dateOfInterest
GROUP BY YEAR([TimeStamp]), MONTH([TimeStamp])
```